# How to move a patch to an empty one closer to the origin?

Tags: netlogo

I want my code to be compressed more based on the amount of turtles given in a slider, and I want to focus that onto the origin. If this is my code

```
to solid
  set color blue
  set xcor random sqrt number-of-particles - number-of-particles / 2
  set ycor random sqrt number-of-particles - number-of-particles / 2
  ifelse any? patches with [pcolor = black and count turtles-here = 0]
  [move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = black and count turtles-here = 0]]
  [die]
end
```

how would i include it so that turtles would move to an empty patch closest to the origin? So far I have

```
if number-of-particles < volume * volume
  [move-to one-of patches with [
```

Comment: Do you have some more context? What is this on about, what language etc.?

Comment: The language is netlogo. Sorry I forgot to add that! Here's a picture: https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10481795_821533417866600_908696988_n.jpg?oh=df59c8dbc5a5762a2a7375aeb0327f34&oe=539E9471&__gda__=1402901356_d28a1fff3d660cf157af481ced14f3de

I want to make it so that the blue circles are centered at the origin and packed together so that they form a square.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that, by "origin", you mean `patch 0 0`, here is a way to do it:

```
to move-near-origin
  let free-patches patches with [pcolor = black and not any? turtles-here]
  ifelse any? free-patches [
    move-to min-one-of free-patches [ distance patch 0 0 ]
  ]
  [ die ]
end
```

The two key pieces are [`min-one-of`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#min-one-of) and [`distance`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#distance).

Also notice that I've replaced `count turtles-here = 0` by `not any? turtles-here`, which basically does the same thing but is more readable. I've also stored `patches with [pcolor = black and not any? turtles-here]` in the `free-patches` variable so you don't have to repeat yourself and test all patches for the condition twice.